# SSL_write stops at \0 character

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, message-queue

How can I make `SSL_write` write a certain amount of bytes without stopping at \0? I am not using strlen to determine the length, I am using an absolute number, e.g.

```
SSL_write(_ssl, buf, 100);
```

Or could this be a problem of `SSL_read`? I am using an absolute number for the amount of bytes here, too.

I have a small SSL client and server. The server is supposed to echo messages it gets. The message reaches the server just fine, but on its way back to the client it gets truncated at the first byte that's \0. There doesn't seem to be anything left to be read with `SSL_read`, because I can send the same message multiple times and I always receive only the first part.

Comment: how do you know it ended at the null?

Comment: Code please. The usual error is to assume that read calls fill the buffer, instead of taking accou tif he count ereturned by the read API?

Comment: @Yakk: I am printing the whole buffer to the console, one byte after another.

Comment: @EJP: I need some time, as the code is big.